# Pico power management in micropython

Tags: power, pi-pico, micropython

I have one of those new Pi Picos, and as I understand great power savings can be had by putting the pico into sleep mode. I can see from the CPU spec sheet that this is possible, however I can't find out whether this is exposed in micropython for it (doesn't look like it).

Two questions really:

1. Is there a way to control this in Python?
2. If not, is there a way to poke the memory to get it to do this anyway (I've seen this done in some other examples with the RTC, so presumably this can be done too?)

Comment: (1) Have you read the hello_sleep.c? (1) pico-playground/sleep/hello_sleep/hello_sleep.c
https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-playground/blob/master/sleep/hello_sleep/hello_sleep.c#L63%20sleep_run_from_xosc();

Comment: perhaps it works using the normal micropython code.. http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.2/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/powerctrl.html perhaps.. I'll try this

Comment: nope, doesn't have machine.RTC()

Comment: But hello_sleep.c does not use machine.RTC.

Comment: yes, but the 'standard' micropython library has sleep functions within machine.RTC(). I've now started writing custom firmware to expose the C functions in python.. not under machine.rtc, I'll be writing a blog post about it shortly.

Comment: Yes, right now I am using Chinese Win10 Python 3.9 Thonny 3.3.3 to play with Rpi Pico. Some years back I used PyBoard and MicroBit MicroPython 3 but found REPL very time consuming and many of the standard python 3 built functions were not implemented. This time round I am still finding Rpi Pico python interpreter lacking some standard built in functions. So I think it might be difficult for Rpi Pico python to run tricked C functions.  / to continue, ...

Comment: For Rpi3B stretch, I found it not that difficult to just blindly follow some tutorials. Just now I casually googled some tools, but I have no confidence they would work smoothly for Pico. References: (1) Calling C Functions from Python - JournalDev 2109dec
https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python

(2) Python Bindings: Calling C or C++ From Python - Jim Anderson 2020mar
https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's you who wrote the post, but after a few months since you asked the question I found this:
https://ghubcoder.github.io/posts/awaking-the-pico/

Comment: leaving it here just for next person who'll search for Pico power management

Comment: @BartoszRakowski: Good catch!  The [URL you posted](https://ghubcoder.github.io/posts/awaking-the-pico/) is the most useful bit of information in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep modes *are* exposed through MicroPython on the Pico but there are some limitations. For more details take a look at PR [#8832](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/8832) and [#9438](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/9438).